# Parse downloading PDF when button is clicked.

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, download

Ok so I have a Parse database holding an array of PDF files that are shown in my table view. When a user selects a file he is taken to a detail view of the chosen PDF and they are given a "Download" option button. I carry the information over a segue from my table view using the same array. Here is how the code looks like.

This is the file i want to be carried over in my segue:

```
detailVC.PDFfile=[[PDFArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"PDFFile"];
```

these are my declarations in for the file in detail h.

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) PFFile * PDFfile;
- (IBAction)Download:(id)sender;
```

I want to program this button to initiate download onto persons device, if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an ordinary download.

You can use `NSURLConnection` with a `NSURLRequest`. It's all very simple and the info you need is in the docs.

Comment: Is there no way to use the PDFFile that I had in my Array and pull it from there? I feel that would be simpler, but not sure if possible

Comment: I assume that the `PDFFile` object is just a data object with some fields, including the download URL. If the data object contains the actual file as a data BLOB (which I doubt is practical) you could of course just save it to a file.